# threading in c# windows service

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading

In a windows service project in c# I create 2 threads to execute 2 jobs.  When looking at the process explorer tool I see more than 30 threads created for the process.  Debugging through my code I don't see more than 2 threads being created.  I'm not sure why I'm seeing so many threads for the process in the process explorer.

The threads are supposed to run every 2 minutes so I call Thread.Sleep(time).

Any ideas why I'm seeing so many threads in my process explorer?

The jist of what I'm seeing is shown below, but instead of 4 threads I'm saying a whole lot more:

```
Process                 PID     Type    Name
MyService.vshost.exe    1234    Thread  MyService.vshost.exe(1234) 1265
MyService.vshost.exe    1234    Thread  MyService.vshost.exe(1234) 6528
MyService.vshost.exe    1234    Thread  MyService.vshost.exe(1234) 3175
MyService.vshost.exe    1234    Thread  MyService.vshost.exe(1234) 5325
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you post the output of process explorer so we can see what you are concerned about?

Comment: @Steve I don't have access to my output at the moment.  I can try and post something soon.  What concerns me is that I am expecting only 2 threads for the process ID.  I'm seeing a lot more threads for the processID.  I'm concerned about performance and going through the code I can't seem to find where more threads are being created.

Comment: The .Net framework will have its own threads running for GC etc. I just tried running a brand new console project - 12 threads with debugger attached, 4 without. BTW, is this actually anything to do with asp.net?

Comment: If all your Windows service does is run some job every two minutes, it probably shouldn't be a service at all, but rather a console application that is run as a scheduled task. See [Programs are not cats](http://blog.mischel.com/2013/02/01/programs-are-not-cats/)

Answer (score 1):

VS doesn't show the other threads because the the debugger is attached to the managed code but most of those threads run `native` code only.

For attaching to the native code, open `Attach to Process` window, click `Select` and in the `Select Code Type` window select Native as well as Managed.

[image: Visual Studio Code Type Window]

Now you can see all the threads in the threads window: managed and native.